# Cases to variables in R (like SPSS)

Tags: r, pivot, reshape

I am trying to spread my rows over multiple columns based on a particular column.
The result should be a dataframe with a unique recordid and a group of columns
based on the unique values in another column.

```
recordid location measA measB measC
     1     body  <NA>     5  <NA>
     2     body  <NA>   >10 text1
     2     head  <0.1  <0.1  <NA>
     3     body  0.02   0.5 text2
     3     head  <NA>  <NA> text3
     3     toes  <0.1  <0.1   >20
```

Here, the location-variable is the grouping for the measurement-columns. The result should be something like:

```
recordid measA_body measA_head measA_toes measB_body measB_head measB_toes measC_body measC_head measC_toes
     1         <NA>     <NA>       <NA>          5       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
     2         <NA>     <0.1       <NA>        >10       <0.1       <NA>      text1       <NA>       <NA>
     3         0.02     <NA>       <NA>        0.5       <NA>       <NA>      text2      text3       >20
```

In SPSS this is the cases to variables function in the restructure-menu but I have not found a simular function of some sort in R. I tried some form of pivot_wider but cannot get it to work on multiple columns. What would be the best way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = location, values_from = c(measA, measB, measC))
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  recordid measA_body measA_head measA_toes measB_body measB_head measB_toes
     <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1        1 <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       5          <NA>       <NA>      
2        2 <NA>       <0.1       <NA>       >10        <0.1       <NA>      
3        3 0.02       <NA>       <0.1       0.5        <NA>       <0.1      
# ... with 3 more variables: measC_body <chr>, measC_head <chr>,
#   measC_toes <chr>
```

---

With data:

```
df <-
structure(list(recordid = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), location = c("body", 
"body", "head", "body", "head", "toes"), measA = c("<NA>", "<NA>", 
"<0.1", "0.02", "<NA>", "<0.1"), measB = c("5", ">10", "<0.1", 
"0.5", "<NA>", "<0.1"), measC = c("<NA>", "text1", "<NA>", "text2", 
"text3", ">20")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Comment: Yes, that is it: specifying all columns in values_from argument and making sure that there are no other columns present except for the id-column. Thanks!